# Date intime taking as outtime and outtime taking as next date intime

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I need a help. Actually I am a admin of a bio-metric device. There are 3 shifts are going in my office.

```
In time   Out time
1. 6AM-   2PM 
2. 2PM-   10PM 
3. 10PM-  6AM
```

but the 3rd shift time intime 10PM is taking as

```
 In time          Out Time
day1   out time      10PM
day2 in time 6AM
```

How can I make it for same date 10PM as intime and 6AM as out time in excel?

Comment: Do you want a Date/Time solution, so that each "Out time" = "In time" + 8? Do you need this for other calculations? Wouldn't just text labels work? For the last request, you want to show just *6AM*, without any dates? That can be done just by changing Number Formatting.

Answer (score 0):

### Change Number Formatting

If you only want to see the hours, not the next day date, you can just change the number formatting.
For demonstration, I am using "day hours AM/PM" format, or `dd hh AM/PM`.
[image]

Now, you can just change the number formatting, to show only time. Like so:

[image]

### Change actual values in cells

You can check, if your value is `>1`, meaning it's second day, and you can subtract `1` to get the same day.
[image]

Comment: I need the both 10PM as intime and 6AM as OUTTIME for the same date.Because next day might be a holiday so how can somebody came to office on a holiday?

FOR EXAMPLE

DATE                INTIME          OUTTIME

05.04.2017       10PM              6AM 

for the same date like for shift3 OUTTIME = OUTTIME DATE-1 
means 6AM on 6th April must showing as 5th April